# How do I maximize my speed at the beginning of a round?

Tags: rocket-league

In rocket league, there is a countdown before you can start driving, but you can start revving your engine before the countdown has finished. You can also choose when to start boosting.

Is there a strategy for when to start your engine, similar to mario kart? Is there also a strategy for your boost? I want to get as many of those precious "first touch" points as I can.

Comment: First touches aren't all that precious though. Sure they yield points, but in most cases, they mean nothing, as the first one hitting the ball is far from guaranteed of landing the best hit on the ball on faceoff.
You'll often see the team landing the first touch ending up with the ball floating towards their own zone, which is not desirable.

Comment: Takes practice.  Boost for around a second, then frontflip and let off the boost until your car is facing forward again.  The timing is tricky, but I get first touch almost every kick doing this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from my experience the best strategy, almost guarantied 100% first touch is to hold accelerate and boost before the match starts, then when you're all out of boost do a front flips, they give a bit of boost towards the direction you flip.

Using this strategy I'm almost certain to get first touch should I want it (sometimes I let them push the ball towards me and do a fast counter with a flip).

Although if you are a center spawn, and you have a teammate on either side, don't bother, it's next to impossible to get first touch in that situation.

Comment: I want to emphasize this sentence: **let them push the ball towards me and do a fast counter** - From my experience, this is by *far* a better approach to kick off than struggling to get first hit - yielding much more goals from kick off than first hit ever could.

Comment: This is good advice, but mostly applies to *after* the countdown has ended. Is there a best time to start accelerating *before* the countdown has finished? Similar to how accelerating right after the *2* in Mario Kart gives you a boost, but too much before that and you will blow out.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Well yeah, because general there is no information I can find on the internet if revving your engine helps or not. In games like Need For Speed where you have cars with different stats and performance, achieving RPM that is in the "green zone" for your specific engine helps the car change the first gear faster ... But in rocket league where all the cars are meant to have the same stats, same engine, same everything, and there is nothing remotely connected to gear shifting, I seriously doubt revving the engine has any effect on your start.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I use all the boost (or almost all) but not straight at the beginning, I tend more to use half of the boost, flip and use the rest while in the air right after the flip aiming my car at the ball.

Doing this, you have almost no chances of being thrown after hitting the ball, which gives you advantage if your oponent is. The problem with this tactic is that there's almost no possibility (unless the other player fails) to get a free goal (if 1v1) but there's no chance for him either.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is when it's a one on one (other players are positioned further away and you're in a corner), you hold the gas right off the start then right as you're about to hit the first boost hold the boost down and then when you're about to reach that center circle, flip forward. If you practice this enough, the opponent will hit the ball right at you and it'll go over them into the opponent's corner. Try to counter the angle at which they go at for best results. Now say you're in the net and no one is on the corners (standard game mode, one center and 2 other of left and right). The best way I've found is to let the guy who's technically the goalie go for the ball. The few steps back that he is, is perfect timing. Gas and Boost right towards it and flip just after hitting the last boost before the ball. Should bounce over to the ceiling and towards their net. You can score off the draw very easily. If you can't use any of these, I would suggest boost and gas till you reach that center circle around the ball then flip. This obviously changes depending on the map but this is my general rule of thumb. If you need screenshots for a better understanding, I will provide them